# SQL incrementing help

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
 1. Name---ID--- SEQ
 2. *---------101--1
 3. *---------101--2
 4. *---------101--3
 5. *---------999--1
 6. *---------999--2
```

Iqnore the -'s

What im importing is Name, ID, and other fields. What im trying to assign is SEQ. I'm not sure how to reset a count when I get to the 2nd group.
Im using MS SQL Server 2005

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Maybe give more information.

Comment: you need more detail.  Which database are you using?  Do you want the row number in a select command or are you trying to insert?

Answer (score 1):

In your import you can calculate sequence as follows

```
INSERT INTO DestTable
SELECT Name, ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS SEQ
FROM SourceTable
```

From your example data it is unclear how you determine within an ID partition what is 1,2,3 etc. Maybe you would need to change the above to `PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name` or something else. At the moment it will be arbitrary.

Comment: SEQ is just incremented for example if another row of data is entered with and ID of 101 it would be 4, and if a row of data is entered with 102 it would be 1

Comment: Well the query in my answer should do that for a one time import but why are you storing this anyway? You can easily use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY identitycol)` in your select queries and you won't have the hassle of trying to keep this updated ongoing.

Comment: Do you have to address the situations where a row is deleted?  Do the SEQ values change?  What if a row is updated where ID changes?

Comment: That is all handled on the frontin database app